# Feeding ServerSide data into JavaScript object constructor

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, object, constructor

I am using ASP.NET MVC and I have a simple requirement. I need to be able to "inject" two server side values into my JavaScript object.

My JavaScript object lives in a separate js file referenced by my project BUT I need to be able to inject data into my object prior to it being used for the first time.

My code currently looks like this.

```
var ImageSizeEnum = {
    Small: 0,
    Medium: 1,
    Large: 2
};

var UrlBuilder = (function (baseImageUrl, storageContainer) {

    var _baseImageUrl = baseImageUrl;
    var _storageContainer = storageContainer;

    this.BuildImageUrl = function (stockImage, imageSizeEnum) {
            var imageSizeString = "";
            switch (imageSizeEnum) {
                case ImageSizeEnum.Small:
                    imageSizeString = "sm";
                    break;
                case ImageSizeEnum.Medium:
                    imageSizeString = "md";
                    break;
                case ImageSizeEnum.Large:
                    imageSizeString = "lg";
                    break;
            }

            var url = kendo.format(_baseImageUrl + "_{2}{3}", _storageContainer, stockImage.AzureId, imageSizeString, stockImage.Extension);
            return url;
    };

});
```

and it is invoked in my `_Layout.cshtml` page like this.

```
$(function () {
    UrlBuilder("@WebConfigSettings.BaseImageUrlPath", "@WebConfigSettings.AzureStorageContainer");
});
```

But this code doesn't appear to work as I expected due to `BuildImageUrl` being undefined. I assume this is because I am not actually initializing and returning my UrlBuilder object by invoking it with () at declaration.

I am somewhat aware of the different types of JavaScript object patterns (i.e. literals, function etc) but I am completely uncertain about what the 'correct' pattern and approach is to solve my particular problem.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `this.BuildImageUrl` to really mean `assign BuildImageUrl to my UrlBuilder object` you'll have to properly construct the object using the `new` keyword.

The difference being:

1- Without `new`: `this` refers to whatever current context exists while executing, in this case I'd say it's the global window object. So `UrlBuilder.BuildImageUrl` will always be null because you're technically doing `window.BuildImageUrl = ...`

2- With `new`:

```
var builder = new UrlBuilder(
    "@WebConfigSettings.BaseImageUrlPath", "@WebConfigSettings.AzureStorageContainer");
```

`this` now correctly refers to the new `builder` object. So `builder.BuildImageUrl` will be defined.

If you want to access the new builder you can do something like:

```
window.urlBuilder = new UrlBuilder(
    "@WebConfigSettings.BaseImageUrlPath", "@WebConfigSettings.AzureStorageContainer");
```

And so from anywhere:

```
urlBuilder.BuildImageUrl(...)
```

**Note:** depending on the framework you're using (or if you're even using one), for example angular, there might be a much better way than doing `window.urlBuilder` since this is commonly referred to as "polluting the global state". But many times this is all you need.

Comment: Thanks very much, sincerely appreciate the breakdown.